# Accessing Redux State from React Component : Connect not work

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

As I understand I should be able to access Redux state inside a React Component if I use Connect from react-redux and then use function mapStateToProps which should send redux state as props to component?

In this following code I try to do that, and I tried all sorts of ways, but it does not work.

Here is code of a react component.
After the imports I write mapStateToProps functions, after which I i thought Id get state.
I know state contains a bit of data, for example profile. So I thought Id make test = state.profile and a bit later in code I will JSON stringify props, and results is only a article json string.

After code you will see an image from Chrome Dev Tools where you can see that state contains many things.
Id like to access them in this component. What am I doing wrong and how can I make it work?

From Image you see state has 'common' field, where there is 'token' and 'currentUser' data inside. Id like to check those values specifically in this component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import agent from '../agent';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ARTICLE_FAVORITED, ARTICLE_UNFAVORITED } from '../constants/actionTypes';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
       return {test: state.profile}
       }

const FAVORITED_CLASS = 'btn btn-sm btn-primary';
const NOT_FAVORITED_CLASS = 'btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  favorite: slug => dispatch({
    type: ARTICLE_FAVORITED,
    payload: agent.Articles.favorite(slug)
  }),
  unfavorite: slug => dispatch({
    type: ARTICLE_UNFAVORITED,
    payload: agent.Articles.unfavorite(slug)
  })
});

const ArticlePreview = props => {
**console.log(JSON.strinify(props));**
  const article = props.article;
  const favoriteButtonClass = article.favorited ?
    FAVORITED_CLASS :
    NOT_FAVORITED_CLASS;

  const handleClick = ev => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (article.favorited) {
      props.unfavorite(article.slug);
    } else {
      props.favorite(article.slug);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="article-preview">
      <div className="article-meta">
        <Link to={`/@${article.author.username}`}>
          <img src={article.author.image} alt={article.author.username} />
        </Link>

        <div className="info">
          <Link className="author" to={`/@${article.author.username}`}>
            {article.author.username}
          </Link>
          <span className="date">
            {new Date(article.createdAt).toDateString()}
          </span>
        </div>

        <div className="pull-xs-right">
          <button className={favoriteButtonClass} onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className="ion-heart"></i> {article.favoritesCount}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Link to={`/article/${article.slug}`} className="preview-link">
        <h1>{article.title}</h1>
        <p>{article.description}</p>
        <span>Read more...</span>
        <ul className="tag-list">
          {
            article.tagList.map(tag => {
              return (
                <li className="tag-default tag-pill tag-outline" key={tag}>
                  {tag}
                </li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default connect(() => ({}), mapDispatchToProps)(ArticlePreview);
```

[image]

Comment: What does the reducer do, are you mutating the state?

Comment: Your mapStateToProps is not doing anything and always returns an empty object: `export default connect((state) => ({thing:state.thingfromState}), `

Comment: Thank You!!!!! I didnt understand to export !!!! IT WORKS :D I was so frusturated the whole day. I just started to learn redux

Comment: @HMR it looks like they created  a `mapStateToProps` function at the top of the file but they haven't actually used it.  `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ArticlePreview);`

Comment: @Jeekim it is better to learn with the hooks `useSelector` and `useDispatch` than with `connect`.  `connect` is sort of "outdated".